# Using a PHP variable in Jquery using PHO echo not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to post data from this script to a test page which contains my INSERT QUERY , I'm trying to post Subject and ID , but I am able to send only subject, not the ID, this ID is a variable in PHP and this script and PHP variable are on the same page. but when I try to pass the ID manually to the insert query it is working and inserting the subject data.
I think  I am not able to transport the PHP var into Jquery properly.

I used Json_encode also but that also didn't work. I am new to this, I do not know too much about details.

```
$(function() {
    var subject;
    var dataString;
    var id;

    $(".notes").click(function() {

        id = <?php echo $id;?>;
        subject = $("#textarea").val();
        dataString = 'subject='+ subject  ;

        if(subject=='')
        {
            $('.ryt').fadeOut(1000).hide();

            $('.ntryt').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.ntryt').fadeOut(5000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/test.php",
                data:{dataString,id}
                success: function(){
                    $('.ryt').fadeIn(1000).show();
                    $('.ryt').fadeOut(2000).show();
                    $('.ntryt').fadeOut(200).hide();

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: is your $id defined before click function??

Comment: You shouldn't and cannot do it!! `jquery` works on client side and `php` works on server side.

Comment: have you initialize id mean by $id='';

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: Care to elaborate? This is how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen How will `id = <?php echo $id;?>;` work?

Comment: @Sibu should i define the var id before the click function? like var id; id = <?php echo $id;?>;

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: The PHP engine parses the .php file and executes the PHP code. `id = <?php echo $id;?>;` echoes the value of the variable `$id` into the resulting page. Just as it's supposed to.

Comment: @Sani A much better way..`<div id='<?php echo $id ;?>' class="notes"> ` ..`$(".notes").click(function() {var id = this.id;
`

Comment: @AdityaKumar i was asking is your php variable id defined before you call click function

Comment: yes, id is already defined into the page and i am echoing it several time in the page, actually it's a id of a person and am i am populating data on the page based on this id.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: id is a local variable in the OP. Are you sure the OP wants to change the id of the div?

Comment: @AdityaKumar please alert id and tell what output you are getting

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I felt so. if you see OP's comments in the answer below,he is unable to send the id from php to script.

Comment: i am not able to alert it.. inside the script but when i am using a diff set of `<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

    var id = <?php echo $id;?>;
    alert(id);

/* ]]> */
</script>
`it is working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data:{dataString,id}` is not valid.

It should be:

```
data:{subject: subject, id: id},
```

Comment: but when i am passing only  `data:dataString,` it is working and passing the subject data..

Comment: @AdityaKumar Yes, you could use a string or an object for the `data`. If you want to use string style, then should be `data: dataString + '&id=' +id`.

Comment: i tried ur solution but it didn't work, i think the 'id' is not set

Comment: @xdazz- thanx it worked, i passed  data:{subject: subject, id: '10'}, and it worked , now i need to figure out how to pass the id from php to this script.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Try my solution in comments